# I need to do some pattern matching with more than one pattern as input in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do some pattern matching to process a list of questions and come up with
some statements that will head the list of solutions. Every question that I need to match 
has a first sentence that ends in a "?". For example if have the following string:

```
input="Which of the following can be aa ... zz?"
```

then I need to see if this matches some predefined patterns and if it does then I need to populate two variables. In this example the string above needs to result in the following:

```
string1= "Can be aa ... zz:"
string2= "Cannot be contained aa ... zz:"
```

Where the text aa ... zzz in the source appears in the destination.

```
Inputs:

1 - Which of the following can be aa ... zz?
2 - Which of the following are correct?
3 - What will result when aa ... zz?
4 - Which of the following is a aa ... zz?
5 - Which are aa ... zz?
6 - What can be said about aa ... zz:
7 - Which of the following is true?
8 - What will be the result when aa ... zz?

Output 1:

1 - Can be aa ... zz:
2 - Correct:
3 - The following will result::
4 - A aa ... zz
5 - The following are aa ... zz
6 - True statement(s)
7 - True statement(s)
8 - The following will result:

Output 2:

1 - Cannot be aa ... zz:
2 - Incorrect:
3 - The following will not result
4 - Not a aa ... zz:
5 - Are not aa ... zz:
6 - False statement(s)
7 - False statement(s)
8 - The following will not result
```

I am thinking that I should store the input pattern and output patterns in a reference data class and then maybe some combination of link and pattern matching.

Does anyone have any suggestions. Even if I could see how to do one match that would be good. 
If I have an example for one then I can code in more and work from that.

What kind of patterns? - The patterns are the text. So for example I am looking to see if my input string starts with "Which of the following can be" and ends with a "?".

Where are these questions coming from? - A limited set of questions. If I cannot get a match then I will put in something like "True" or "False" in the outputs.

Comment: What kind of patterns? What are you using, regex? Where are these questions coming from, is it a limited set of possible values or are you parsing books? A little bit more detail and anything you already have to handle it will probably be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added some more notes to the questions. Hope it helps. I am just looking for a simple suggestion just to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be modeled something like below:

```
static Tuple<string,string> Match(string question)
{
   //Do the matching and return the string,string tuple where first 
   //string is for output 1 and second for output 2.
}

static Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> GetOutput(List<string> questions)
{
    var r = questions.Select(q => Match(q));
    return new Tuple<List<string>,List<string>(r.Select(t => t.Item1).ToList(), r.Select(t =>  t.Item2).ToList());
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this only work for exact matches? I think I need to use somethink like regex as the "aa ... zz" portion of my string could be any sequence except something ending in "?"

Comment: Yes, inside Match function either use substring or regex to find the appropriate pattern