# How can I match a pattern and extract out a part of it in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following text in a string that always ends in a "?".

```
"Which of the following can be abc def ghi?"
"Which of the following can be hello?"
```

Can someone tell me how I can check to see if this text contains:

```
"Which of the following <any string of text here>?"
```

and if it contains that then how can I get the text "abc def ghi" and "hello"

Comment: Introducing [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e.aspx).

Comment: Why wouldn't the results be "can be abc def ghi" and "can be hello". This doesn't need RegEx just a simple `string.IndexOf`.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Ideally I am looking for a RegEx solution. What I have now is just a simple example that I hoped could get me started. I have a lot more advanced things. I just didn't put them here because I thought I could do that myself. Thanks very much. I hope someone has a RegEx example :-)

Comment: @Christine - Someone did post a RegEx solution then deleted it as they presumably thought it overkill. Best to make sure that your question reflects your actual requirements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const string constantValue = "Which of the following can be ";
var theString = "Which of the following can be abc def ghi?";
var index = theString.IndexOf(constantValue);

string result = "";
if (index > -1)
    result = theString.Substring(constantValue.Length, 
                            theString.Length - constantValue.Length - index - 1);
```

**Edit:**
This **regex** should match all the inputs from your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7219719/14484):

```
var text = "1 - Which of the following is a aa mmm zz?\n" +
"2 - Which of the following is true?\n" +
"3 - Which of the following can be aa mmm zz?\n" +
"4 - Which of the following are correct?\n" +
"5 - What will be the result when aa mmm zz?\n" +
"6 - What will result when aa mmm zz?\n" +
"7 - Which are aa mmm zz?\n" +
"8 - What can be said about aa mmm zz?\n";

var regex = @"What (can be said about |will (be the )?result when )(?<result>.*?)\?|Which (of the following )?(can be|are|is|is a) (?<result>.*?)[?:]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("result: " + match.Groups["result"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [String.StartsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228630.aspx) to check for the existence of a substring.
you can use [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) to split a string according to a specified substring.

you could also [use regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx), if you understand them (which i don't...)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str.Length > "Which of the following".Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("Which of the following", "").Replace("can be" , "").Trim());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have so many of these to do. I was hoping just for a one line regex that I could try and put in a LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the entire input string, and ensure that the input string begins with the beginning of the question, use this:

```
  static string ExtractQuestionObject(string question)
  {
     const string pattern = "Which of the following ";
     if (question.StartsWith(pattern, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
         && question.EndsWith("?"))
        return question.Substring(pattern.Length, question.Length - pattern.Length - 1);
     else
        return null;
  }
```

If you want to find questions anywhere within the input, use:

```
  static string FindQuestionObject(string text)
  {
     const string pattern = "Which of the following ";
     int questionStart = text.IndexOf(pattern);
     if (questionStart >= 0)
     {
        int questionMark = text.IndexOf('?', questionStart);
        if (questionMark > questionStart)
           return text.Substring(questionStart + pattern.Length,
                  questionMark - questionStart - pattern.Length);
     }
     return null;
  }
```

If you want to use regular expressions to match all the strings with one call, use:

```
  static string[] FindQuestionObjects(string text)
  {
     System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
        @"Which of the following ([^\?]+)\?",
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(text);
     string[] result = new string[mc.Count];
     for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        result[i] = mc[i].Groups[1].Value;
     return result;
  }
```